# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null (anonymous) How to change CSS property of ShadowRoot (open)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typeerror, shadow-dom

[image: ShadowRoot (open)]

**ShadowRoot(open)**

I want to change the **z-index** value of this ShadowRoot.

```
host = document.getElementById("shadow-root");
var style = document.createElement( 'style' )
 style.innerHTML = '.rssapp { z-index: -1; }'
 host.shadowRoot.appendChild( style )
// var sheet = new CSSStyleSheet
// sheet.replaceSync( `.rssapp { z-index: -1 }`)
// host.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [ sheet ]
```

I tried the above piece of code, both the commented and the un-commented one but both times it is showing  **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shadowRoot' of null
    at script.js:35
(anonymous)** 
  or
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shadowRoot' of null
    at script.js:38
(anonymous)** respectively

**Edit:** I tried with the id **XQqyAJD0d17SWeNW** as well.

Comment: Change ```host = document.getElementById("shadow-root");``` to ```var host = document.getElementById("shadow-root");``` .. declare it with ```var``` keyword..

Comment: still not working

Comment: Please look into this https://medium.com/quick-code/understanding-the-shadow-dom-20e691cc611b for  reference..

Comment: I know whar Shadow DOMs are. I need a way to be able to edit the Shadow DOMs CSS property

Comment: const host = document.createElement('style');
host.innerText = `
 .rssapp-feed-card-container {
  z-index: 0;
};`   I have tried this

Comment: What i would assume from the code you provided, this line ```document.getElementById("shadow-root");``` itself would give null.. try ```console.log(host)``` after first line of declaration.. Make sure there is an element with id ```shadow-root``` ..

Comment: yes, it;s showing null. The problem is I am not understanding which ID or class to select so that I can edit the DOM properties

Comment: It is also hard for me to tell without any example from your end.. Provide some working example reproducing your issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just add a style to the selected element? using Jquery maybe:

```
$('#shadow-root .rssapp').attr('style', 'z-index:-1');
```

or maybe something like this:

```
$('.rssapp').attr('style', 'z-index:-1');
```

Please tell me if this works.

Comment: Are you sure your selector not returning null? did you console.log it? I think you should select the element by the ID then call .shadowRoot

Comment: yes it's returning null. I have mentioned it in the question itself